# Multiple Where Has Query in Lumen / Laravel Problem

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen, eloquent-relationship

I just want to ask for help in this specific situation. So, in my application we want to have a global search function where you put 1 string and then we have to search that string in multiple cases in the db using laravel eloquent, however this has become problematic since i have multiple where has and then i have withcount (which i will show later). Can someone help me with this problem? It would be much appreciated

Here is the code

```
    $result = [];
    $sort_order = "DESC";
    $post_param = $request->json()->all();
    $filters = $post_param['filters'];

    if($post_param['sortOrder'] > 0)
    {
        $sort_order = "ASC";
    }

    $financing_applications   = $this->financing_application->model();

    $data                     = $financing_applications::with('financing_application_data.business_type','financing_product_approval.financing_product')->withCount('financing_application_attachments as attachment');

    foreach($filters as $key => $filter){
        $value = $filter['value'];
        if($value != ""){
            switch($key){
                case "start_date_range":
                    $data   = $data->where('submission_date','>=',$value);
                    break;

                case "end_date_range":
                    $data   = $data->where('submission_date','<=',$value);
                    break;

                case "status":
                    $data   = $data->where($key,"LIKE","%$value%");
                    break;

                case "attachment_count":
                    $data   = $data->having('attachment_count','=',$value);
                    break;

                case "company_name":
                case "telephone":
                case "city":
                    if($key == "telephone"){
                        $key = "personal_phone_no";
                    }
                    if($key == "city"){
                        $key = "company_city";
                    }
                    $data   = $data->whereHas('financing_application_data',function($query) use ($key,$value) {
                        $query->where($key,"LIKE","%$value%");
                    });
                    break;

                case "business_type":
                    $data->whereHas('financing_application_data.business_type',function($query) use ($key,$value){
                        $query->where('business_type_parent','LIKE',"%$value%");
                    });
                    break;

                case "loan_type":
                case "loan_partner":
                    $data->whereHas('financing_product_approval.financing_product',function($query) use ($key,$value){
                        $query->where($key,"LIKE","%$value%");
                    });
                    break;

                case "global": //This is the problem
                    $data   = $data->whereHas('financing_application_data.business_type',function($query) use ($key,$value){
                        $query->whereRaw("business_type_parent LIKE ? ",["%$value%"]);
                    });
                    $data   = $data->whereHas('financing_product_approval.financing_product',function($query) use ($key,$value){
                        $query->whereRaw("loan_type LIKE ? OR loan_partner LIKE ?",["%$value%","%$value%"]);
                    });
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    $total_records  = $data->count();
    $result         = $data->orderBy($post_param['sortField'],$sort_order)->skip($post_param['first'])->take($post_param['rows'])->get();

    return [
        "financing_applications" => $result,
        "total_records" => $total_records,
        "message" => "",
        "status" => 200,
    ];
```

So, in this case my expected result is just be able to use all of the cases and combine it on "global" case in the switch statement.

Is there anyone that have the same problem and have the solution?
The above global is not working since where and whereHas is expected as AND not OR... and i have been searching for the solution but it's too complicated i don't know the exact keyword for this problem

Here is some of the information you need

```
"laravel/lumen-framework": "5.3.*"
```

Update:
I am sorry if some of you have mistook my problem, so the problem lies on case "global" only, now with the other case lies "whereHas" syntax to filter relationship. On case global should able to combine the "Where" and "WhereHas", I have done that but because of no "orWhereHas" (as long as i know), so it will return empty since it recognize as "AND" statement

Here i give you the json payload:

```
{
"filters": {
    "global": {
        "matchMode": "undefined",
        "type": "string",
        "value": "Man"
    },
    "start_date_range": {
        "matchMode": "undefined",
        "type": "date",
        "value": ""
    },
    "end_date_range": {
        "matchMode": "undefined",
        "type": "date",
        "value": ""
    },
    "company_name": {
        "matchMode": "undefined",
        "type": "string",
        "value": ""
    },
    "business_type": {
        "matchMode": "undefined",
        "type": "string",
        "value": ""
    },
    "telephone": {
        "matchMode": "undefined",
        "type": "string",
        "value": ""
    },
    "city": {
        "matchMode": "undefined",
        "type": "string",
        "value": ""
    },
    "attachment_count": {
        "matchMode": "undefined",
        "type": "string",
        "value": ""
    },
    "loan_type": {
        "matchMode": "undefined",
        "type": "string",
        "value": ""
    },
    "loan_partner": {
        "matchMode": "undefined",
        "type": "string",
        "value": ""
    },
    "status": {
        "matchMode": "undefined",
        "type": "string",
        "value": ""
    }
},
"first": 0,
"rows": 8,
"sortOrder": -1,
"sortField": "submission_date"
}
```

So the goal is to make the filter['global']['value'] return something, that's all the problem, hope it clarifies some understanding issue

Comment: You don't have to use `$data   = $data->where('submission_date','>=',$value);` but only `$data->where('submission_date','>=',$value);`

Comment: I'm sorry but you answer didn't answer my problem

Comment: That's why I commented, and not answered, and what is your problem exactly ?

Comment: I have added a paragraph, might be clearing some misunderstood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around this problem, I have to replace the whereHas syntax with has, which can have OR logic which what i need in this case.

Thank you